# porcentaje de un canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

buenas tengo el siguiente inconveniente lo que sucede es que al momento de hacer un  destination-out quiero calcular el porcentaje del canvas que se ha "eliminado" y al llegar a un 70% eliminar el canvas con hidden o algo por el estilo el problema es que no doy con la solucion para obtener ese porcentaje encontre un modo pero no lo puedo implementar a este modo que es lo que busco

Aqui el codigo

```html
<style> 
.box {
  display: inline-block;
  background: url("https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/4652816/12771954/41dccb10-ca68-11e5-9db8-a473f51426c8.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}

canvas {
  background: transparent;
  position: absolute;
}

.contenido{
    position:absolute;
}


</style>




<div class="box">
<div class="contenido">
<h1> hola </h1>
<button> hola </button>
<a href="#"> llevar </a>
</div>
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</div>


<script>var url = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b6/Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png/1200px-Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png';
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var img = new Image();
img.src = url;
img.onload = function () {
  var width = Math.min(500, img.width);
  var height = img.height * (width / img.width);



           


  canvas.width = width;
  canvas.height = height;
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);
  
};

var isPress = false;
var old = null;
canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function (e){
  isPress = true;
  old = {x: e.offsetX, y: e.offsetY};
});
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function (e){
  if (isPress) {
    var x = e.offsetX;
    var y = e.offsetY;
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x, y, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.fill();

    ctx.lineWidth = 70;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(old.x, old.y);
    ctx.lineTo(x, y);
    ctx.stroke();


    old = {x: x, y: y};

    

  }
});
canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', function (e){
  isPress = false;
});



</script>
```

El objetivo es que cuando llegue al 70% este se pueda borrar
por que no me permite dar click a los botones de los otros elementos

Answer (score 0):

de momento lo solucione con esto haciendo el efecto de que si lo rasca por asi decirlo mas de 300 veces se elimine y me permite usar los botones de abajo

```html
<style> 
.box {
  display: inline-block;
  background: url("https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/4652816/12771954/41dccb10-ca68-11e5-9db8-a473f51426c8.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}

canvas {
  background: transparent;
  position: absolute;
}

.contenido{
    position:absolute;
}


</style>




<div class="box">
<div class="contenido">
<h1> hola </h1>
<button> hola </button>
<a href="#"> llevar </a>
</div>
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</div>


<script>
var raspaditas = 0;
var url = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b6/Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png/1200px-Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png';
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var img = new Image();
img.src = url;
img.onload = function () {
  var width = Math.min(500, img.width);
  var height = img.height * (width / img.width);

   


  canvas.width = width;
  canvas.height = height;
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);
  
};

var isPress = false;
var old = null;
canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function (e){
  isPress = true;
  old = {x: e.offsetX, y: e.offsetY};
});
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function (e){
  if (isPress) {
    var x = e.offsetX;
    var y = e.offsetY;
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x, y, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.fill();

    ctx.lineWidth = 70;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(old.x, old.y);
    ctx.lineTo(x, y);
    ctx.stroke();


    old = {x: x, y: y};

    raspaditas++;
   if(raspaditas > 300){
       canvas.style.visibility = "hidden";
   }

  }
});
canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', function (e){
  isPress = false;
});


 

</script>
```

Aunque se que no es el mejor modo precisamente pero al menos funciona un poco.  Igual estare al tanto. solo lo dejo por aqui por si acaso alguien mas tenga la misma duda y aun no encuentre la solucion